# Android: run method of type Runnable must override a supertype method

Tags: android, multithreading, overriding

I'm having trouble with an Android activity: I'm trying to create a splash screen for an app which will be displayed during 3 seconds.

Yet, I get a persistant error in a portion of the code which is the following (the error):

"The method run() of type new Runnable(){} must override or implement a supertype method"

Here's the section:

```
final Runnable execution = new Runnable(){

@Override
public void run() {

    Intent login = new Intent(ctx,LoginScreen.class);
    startActivity(login);
    finish();           
}

};
```

And the rest of the code:

```
package com.example.events;

import com.example.events.LoginScreen;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Runnable extends Activity {

    Context ctx;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_runnable);
        ctx=this;
        Threads();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.runnable, menu);
        return true;
    }

    final Handler mHandler= new Handler();

    public void Threads(){

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } 

                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                mHandler.post((java.lang.Runnable) execution);
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    }

    final Runnable execution = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent login = new Intent(ctx,LoginScreen.class);
            startActivity(login);
            finish();           
        }

    };

}
```

I DID check my project properties and the Compiler IS set at 1.6 yet the error won't leave: is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help.

Mauro.

Comment: Rename you Activity class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Activity` is named `Runnable`. Hence, your `final Runnable execution = new Runnable()` is attempting to create an instance of `com.example.events.Runnable`, which does not have a `run()` method.

There are a near-infinite number of possible class names. Please choose a different one for your `Activity` subclass, one that does not collide with another class name that is commonly used in Java or Android. For example, you might choose `Ddskwerioajsdlv` as the name of your `Activity` subclass, as that name does not appear to be used.